# What exactly is the 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly' and how can I make it load manually?

Tags: c#, .net

As a .NET developer, the line

```
'<process name>' (Managed): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
```

probably is familiar to you. My question is simple and straightforward: what exactly is this 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly' and can I make it (pre)load manually? If so, how? Can this be done via Assembly.Load(...)?

Comment: It's not familiar to me! But I just saw it and would like to know what it is.

Comment: In my case the issue was when I used linq query and comparing varchar with integer. like: where(t => t.String.Equals(1)). the fix was where(t => t.String.Equals("1")). to compare string integer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

System.Reflection.Emit contains classes that allows you to create dynamically generated code by emitting IL instructions.  The DynamicMethod and AssemblyBuilder classes are the work-horses for doing so.  IL normally is loaded from an assembly, but there is no assembly when you generate the IL dynamically.  An assembly object is however needed to act as the container of the IL code and a "fake" one is created by AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly().  That's what you see in the debugger notification.

You can't use Assembly.Load(), the assembly is created dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to determine when this dynamically created assembly object is created?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'determine' as in 'influence', not 'identify' :-) So could one advance or delay the loading of dynamic assembly objects?

Comment: Erm, yes, don't execute the code that uses Reflection.Emit.  You'll have to find it first.

Comment: OK. The point is: in the project I'm currently working on, this loading takes quite some time when a certain piece of code is reached. What I tried to do was to move the loading of this dynamic assembly to the startup phase of the application. But if I understand you correctly, this could be quite some challenge.

Comment: Erm, so you don't actually want to delay it, you want to run it sooner.  That still requires you finding out where that code is located and what method call is required to run it.  Surely there's a programmer out there somewhere that wrote that code and knows the answer?  She might be in the next cubicle?

Answer (score 2):

This is for DynamicMethods and thus goes for expressions too.

You cannot load it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I started to encounter the exception after I tweaked some Visual Studio settings. I encountered the exception on Html helpers in my MVC view.
I found out that I had unchecked the checkbox for "Enable Just My Code".

The issue got resolved for me after I checked the checkbox.
Below are the steps for Visual Studio 2022:

1. Go to: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General
2. Check the checkbox for "Enable Just My Code"

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is an assembly emitted at run time. Since it's not required to save the assembly to disk, it may not be possible to load it manually (in this case when the code finishes emitting the assembly - into memory - it will use the types defined in the assembly directly - no need to load anything)

For more information see the [documentation in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilder(v=VS.100).aspx).

Best

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I just encountered it recently.
My code works fine, the thing I can remember I did beforehand is upgraded to the latest telerik update.
Then I upgraded my current solution, when i run my application the error appears...
The error popups around Html helper "Html.TextboxFor", "Html.PasswordFor" is fine,